# loop over multiple forms and send attr value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop over multiple forms and send a attr vhid value to a cgi in the backend. The problem is the alert is showing the first value twice. I am very bad at javascript and would appreciate some help.

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sping").each(function () {
        $('form#spingForm').ready(function () { // Form is submitted
            var data = $('#vhid').attr('value'); // get device name
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="sping">
    <div id="spingResult-1"></div>
    <form id="spingForm-1" name="spingForm-1" method="post" action="">
        <input id="vhid" type="vhid" name="vhid" value="1" />
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6"><strong>DATA</strong>
        <br />
        <div class="sping">
            <div id="spingResult-2"></div>
            <form id="spingForm-2" name="spingForm-2" method="post" action="">
                <input id="vhid" type="vhid" name="vhid" value="2" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: You should not use same id for multiple elements, ids should have to be unique for every element.

Comment: you must not have same multiple `id's`

Comment: the input id's should be different? yeah i can get that changed, but then , this line would also change right, var data = $('#vhid').attr('value'); . i dont understand how to select it with different ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, elements within a document must have [**unique IDs**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). JavaScript will only process the first ID and stop looking for anything else. In your example you have two `input` elements with the same ID.

Change your `id` to a `class` instead:

```html
<input class="vhid" type="vhid" name="vhid" value="2"  />
```

Then use jQuery's `each()` method to iterate over all your forms and pull all the values:

```
var vhidArray = [];
$('input.vhid').each(function() {
    vhidArray.push($(this).val());
});
```

Here I've created an array (`vhidArray`) and am then looping through each `input` element with a class of "vhid" (`input.vhid`), pushing its value into the array.

If you had two "vhid" input elements on your page with the values "20" and "hello, world!", you would end up with the following array:

```
vhidArray = ["20", "hello, world!"]
```

You can then pass that array over to your server in your form's submit function.

Answer (score 0):

could not figure it out, then just wrapped the js code in a function and called it after every form.